# How to change TextView link background on hover

Tags: android, textview

I want to change my TextView link background colour while user pressed on links.

I have search the web and found nothing.

The result I want is like picture below. The text `@GeniusVcsh` is pressed and with a light blue background.

[image]

Any help would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Try use `selector`:

First create `selector.xml` in `res\drawable` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

then add `android:background="@drawable/selector"` and `android:clickable="true"` in the `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Hope it helps.

[more reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a class derived from `TextView` to handle links and custom colouring of text just recently. To answer your question, use `Html.fromHtml` function and pass it with HTML's font tag with a color attribute.

```
TextView tvRedText;
...
tvRedText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + "This is a red text " + "</font>"));
```